# Why is the frequency of the "Lord of Hosts" greater in the post-exilic prophets than in any other OT text?

Tags: hebrew, hebrew-bible, torah, linguistics, literary-criticism

While preparing a sermon on Haggai 2 this week, I realized that the designation "Lord of Hosts" occurs 0 times in the Torah, makes up less than a fraction of a percentage of text of the Writings and most of the Prophets, but is 2% of the text of Haggai, Zechariah, and Malachi. The actual data is slightly more nuanced and is reproduced in the table below.

My question is simply can anyone think of a compelling linguistic or literary reason for these drastic shifts in the usage of the "Lord of Hosts" by the biblical writers?

| Books | Hebrew Tokens | יהוה צבאות | Frequency Percentages |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Genesis | 20610 | 0 | 0 |
| Exodus | 16713 | 0 | 0 |
| Leviticus | 11950 | 0 | 0 |
| Numbers | 16408 | 0 | 0 |
| Deuteronomy | 14294 | 0 | 0 |
| Joshua | 10051 | 0 | 0 |
| Judges | 9885 | 0 | 0 |
| Samuel | 24294 | 11 | 0.000452786696304 |
| Kings | 25412 | 5 | 0.000196757437431 |
| Isaiah | 16923 | 60 | 0.00354547066123 |
| Jeremiah | 21816 | 81 | 0.003712871287129 |
| Ezekiel | 18730 | 0 | 0 |
| Hosea | 2381 | 1 | 0.000419991600168 |
| Joel | 957 | 0 | 0 |
| Amos | 2042 | 9 | 0.004407443682664 |
| Obadiah | 291 | 0 | 0 |
| Jonah | 688 | 0 | 0 |
| Micah | 1396 | 1 | 0.000716332378223 |
| Nahum | 558 | 2 | 0.003584229390681 |
| Habakkuk | 671 | 1 | 0.001490312965723 |
| Zephaniah | 767 | 2 | 0.002607561929596 |
| Haggai | 600 | 12 | 0.02 |
| Zechariah | 3126 | 46 | 0.014715291106846 |
| Malachi | 876 | 24 | 0.027397260273973 |
| Psalms | 19581 | 15 | 0.000766048720699 |
| Proverbs | 6915 | 0 | 0 |
| Job | 8340 | 0 | 0 |
| Song of Songs | 1250 | 0 | 0 |
| Ruth | 1294 | 0 | 0 |
| Lamentations | 1542 | 0 | 0 |
| Ecclesiastes | 2987 | 0 | 0 |
| Esther | 3045 | 0 | 0 |
| Daniel | 2320 | 0 | 0 |
| Ezra | 2541 | 0 | 0 |
| Nehemiah | 5312 | 0 | 0 |
| Chronicles | 24051 | 3 | 0.000124734938256 |

Comment: I won't, but I'm tempted to downvote this simply for the incorrect use of "exponential" :-)

Comment: Hi Ray, I'm glad you didn't down vote for the use of "exponential." However, you should know that my use of the word was not rhetoric. I plotted the frequency percentages of the 39 texts in the table above in ascending order with 1-39 as the x-coordinates and the graph was of the shape y=e^x. That's why I used the term. @RayButterworth

Comment: @DanielOckrin  "Ascending order'?  If you mean you started with the smallest and went to the largest of course you'll get an increasing curve, but that's no way to plot the data.  To plot it in a way relevant to the question you should plot the books in the order in which they were written, and that doesn't even give an increasing curve, let alone exponential; it yields a plot with a high point in Isaiah and Jeremiah.
I don't know what "frequency percentages" means -- occurrences per verse?  occurrences per word?
Additionally if you're relying on a graph you should provide it.

Comment: @Traildude I could not figure out how to post a graph in the comments, otherwise I would have in my reply to RayButterworth. "Frequency percentages" means instances of יהוה צבאות per the number of tokens (as opposed to lemmas) in each text of the OT corpus. Isaiah and Jeremiah are the word count high point for יהוה צבאות, not the frequency high point. The frequency high point is the post-exilic prophets, and I was wondering why. That is my question. My use of the word "exponential" is an unfortunate distraction from getting the help I was seeking. I'm gonna edit it out of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase 'יהוה שבאות' is commonly referred to as the 'battle name' of the Lord. This is because 'hosts' refers to military powers, as seen throughout the Tanakh, but Numbers 10:14 or 1 Chronicles 7:11 are good examples. So, the Lord is the master of armies, both heavenly and earthly. It is a demonstration of his power. For the prophets, the name took on the significance of the Lord's demonstration of power in returning his people from exile. It is notable that in Zechariah 1:3, the name is used three times in a single verse to talk about the return of the people to the Lord, as a precursor to their being brought back from exile to Jerusalem, so as to build the temple.

The Lord does this by utilizing armies. He uses the armies of Babylon and Assyria to punish the people and to send them into exile. He then uses the army of the Persians to release the people from exile. The name then indicates that all these powers, whether they be the heavenly hosts of angels above or the earthly hosts of empires below, are all subservient to the Lord and are utilized for his purposes. The exiles to whom the prophets were writing and who treasured their writings long after their deaths would have thought YHWH wasn't powerful enough to save them from the Gods of Assyria and Babylon. But calling him the Lord of Hosts is the prophets way of saying 'You've got it wrong, he is the one who willed this, and he will return you when the time is right.'

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: Thanks, Shmuel! @ShmuelBenFredricks